# Как правильно написать цикл в python

Tags: python, циклы

условие:
в день я получаю 1000. сколько я получу через 5 дней?

мои потуги:

```
x=1000
i=1
for i in range(5):
    i+=1
    y=sum(x*i)
print(y)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
напишите, пожалуйста правильное решение

Comment: А у меня заодно вопрос к общественности - откуда ошибка  'int' object is not iterable??

Comment: Как вы думаете `y=sum(x*i)` это нормально? Как мы возьмем сумму из этого выражения?

Comment: @MikhailSibirev, функция `sum` предполагает, что ей передают итерируемый объект, а ей передали целое число, отсюда ошибка.

Comment: @insolor, понимания мало, вопросов много, даже вопрос сложно сформулировать. не могли бы вы более развернуто объяснить комментарий?

Comment: @Евген5 Вот подробнее:https://goo.gl/4axiHS

Comment: @Евген5, `sum` возвращает сумму элементов итерируемого объекта (например списка). Итерируемый объект - любой объект, элементы которого можно перебрать, например циклом `for`. Целое число не является итерируемым объектом (конструкция типа `for i in 10` не имеет никакого смысла), а, например, список - является.

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю зачем тут цикл?

Вот пример:

```
def week_salary(salary_on_1_day, day_count):
    return f'За {day_count} дней вы получите {salary_on_1_day * day_count} рублей'
```

Использование:

```
print(week_salary(1000, 5))
```

`1000` - зарплата за 1 день.

`5` - кол-во дней.

Результат:

> За 5 дней вы получите 5000 рублей

Вариант с `lambda` функцией:

```
week_salary = lambda salary_on_1_day, day_count: f'За {day_count} дней вы получите {salary_on_1_day * day_count} рублей'
```

А теперь циклы:

Объявим переменные:

```
const = 1000
day = 5
result = 0
```

Цикл `for`:

```
for i in range(day):
    result += const
```

Цикл `while`:

```
while result < day * const:
    result += const
```

В обоих случаях получим `5000`.

Но не рекомендую для данной задачи использовать циклы.

Comment: не стоит ввод/вывод (очень специфичный для задачи) и вычисления (чистая функция, можно в GUI, web, CLI использовать и тестировать отдельно) смешивать. Кстати, если функция называется `week_salary()`, то второй аргумент стоит убрать: `week_salary = lambda day_rate, work_days=5:  day_rate * work_days` (если не 5 дней работа, то вероятно нужно специальную плату вводить за работу в выходные или за лишние часы (overtime) -- простая функция уже не будет работать). Введение функции ясности не прибавляет здесь, если `work_days` не константа.

Comment: Можно просто: `print(f'За {day_count} дней вы получите {day_rate * day_count}₽')`

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. На счет названия функции,  в неделе может быть 5, 6, 7 рабочих дней, поэтому и не ставил `day_count=5`

Comment: - оба примера с функциями не работают, пробовал как в скрипте, так в среде. у меня есть в голове остатки знаний по паскалю, есть эмпирическое понимание алгоритмов, могу понять матан, тервер, дисмат (графы и булеву алгебру), т.к. была и теория и практика и интерес, но в программировании пока я НОЛЬ, потому я не знаю пока про лямбда-функцию и т.п. так же как и почему ваши варианты не работают

Comment: Можете скинуть ошибку? Какая у вас версия Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
x=1000 
y=0
for i in range(5):  
   y+=x 
print(y)
```

Comment: спасибо! может быть, циклы в данном случае не самое лучшее решение для задачи, но "это" решение - то, что нужно; то, что я пока могу понять

Comment: Кончено, тут циклы не нужны. Просто 5х1000. Но если Вы хотели цикл - то как-то так...